# Multi-team poly-repo pushing to production - How to strategise?

Tags: continuous-delivery, production, delivery

I work within a poly-repo that is worked on by multiple other teams, each in our own separate sections of this main repo.

I am coming to make my first push to production and I am unsure about strategies for doing so.

A traditional code-freeze on the `Master` branch isn't feasible due to the amount of teams and the frequency of code merging here.

One idea that was floated was making a copy of the current `Master` and as `sub-master` at the point where we have the code we want to be released. An issue I thought of with this was around any potential hot-fixes that might need to be made as a result of our production push from here... We can push fixes to the `sub-master`, however these wouldn't be replicated on the `Master`, so if all goes well in the re-testing of these hot-fixes, going back to work on the `Master` branch... They won't have been replicated and the issues in the initial cut of the `sub-master` will persist.

I created a diagram to try and help illustrate my point.

[image]

The traditional diagrams like this are a little confusing to me.

[image]

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a general "right way", surely your colleagues can help you do things "their way"?

Comment: @JacobRaihle I think the issue we have at the moment is that the other team we work most closely with doesn't have a plan, yet they've gone live in the past but nobody seems to have written down how XD

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Are you trying to design a new branching and/or deployment strategy for a product that requires developing, building, and deploying multiple repositories managed by multiple teams? If so, there is a lot of detail needed. How many repos? How many teams? What is the current as-is state for each repo to go from development to deployment?

Comment: It's a repo of repos (not my choice) with multiple teams (I don't know how many) contributing to their own sections. I am wanting to deploy one of these repos within. I'm will have to do some digging on how other teams do things, but I was just looking for suggestions on how something like this might be done from a "code-freeze" perspective when it's not really feasibly in such a large poly-repo

Comment: @physicsboy, it seems the lower diagram which you are struggling to understand, reflects an environment with a far greater level of sophistication than your current workplace. If there are existing structures and practices for how source code is kept, compiled, and released, then you'd naturally ask those responsible about how to do things within the setup they've designed. If you can't get such simple communication lines going, then there's little hope for sustaining these complicated systems of development work like those suggested by your diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

"Poly-repo" doesn't matter here, it just makes it more annoying as there are commits coming in that have nothing to do with your release schedule.

Your "sub-master" corresponds to what other people may call "staging" or "release candidate".

What's wrong with the classic release branch approach:

- branch off `master` to `release_1.0`
- tag that as `release_1.0.0`
- test and deploy `release_1.0`. All teams can continue to commit to `master`
- bug reports come in
- fix bugs against `master` (VERY IMPORTANT)
- you can then either port individual changes to `release_1.0` branch and deploy tag `release_1.0.1`, or you can run the release cycle again and produce `release_1.1`
- it is possible to do further emergency hotfix work as branches off `release_1.0` called e.g. `release_1.0_hotfix`, but those MUST be merged back to `master` as soon as the situation has stabilized.

You should discourage "emergency" work in production as much as possible, preferring instead something like blue-green deployment where it's possible to abandon and reverse a deployment if problems are found.